# RavenDB Slow Query with an Empty DB

Tags: performance, ravendb, linqpad

I just started a new RavenDB server after deleting the data folder. So, I have an empty DB. I ran this query in LinqPad. The first time took 19 seconds, and the second time took 13 seconds. Why would this take so long on an empty database?

```
Session.Query<PerformanceMetric>()
.Where(x => x.CreatedTime > new DateTime(2012, 4, 17, 15, 00, 00))
.OrderBy(x => x.ObjectType)
.OrderBy(x => x.CreatedTime)
.Take(1000)
.ToList().Dump();
```

Note: The third and fourth times I ran the query, it only took .02 seconds. Was it building indexes or something?

Comment: My guess is building indexes. Have you tried creating the indexes it would use before doing the query?

Comment: That's a good idea. I'll try that.

Comment: I added the index before querying and it ran quickly. That must be it. Interesting that it would take that long to build an index and return a query on an empty database. If you want to post your answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Done, a link to where I read about it also. One of those features that I love, because it lets you try things out fast, then make them fast if they are what you need.

Comment: @BobHorn it's takes a while because there is some general overhead of setting up an index, even if there are no docs to index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My best guess is that the time was taken to build the indexes. When you don't create an index ahead of time, RavenDB will let you still query for random things, it will just create an index for you, and if you use it enough, it will keep it around.

Try creating the index ahead of time, and seeing how it will work.

More information can be gotten here: http://ayende.com/blog/4667/ravens-dynamic-queries

Answer (score 3):

The reason it takes a while is that we need to create an index for the query to run, if one isn't already there.
Even if there are no docs, we still need to do some work to prepare for it. In particular, compiling the index is usually the most expensive part.